# Angular Material Table issue (mat-sort-header) - TypeError: Cannot define property __source, object is not extensible

Tags: angular, sorting, angular-material, angular-material-table

I am trying to populate an Angular Material table with sorting specified on one column using MatSort. The table displays fine, and the sorting works too. However, I get this strange error on the console. The error doesn't break the application but I'm taking it as a sign that something is very wrong. The error says:

```js
TypeError: Cannot define property __source, object is not extensible
```

I don't understand what this __source property is, and what is the object that is not extensible.

The table in the template is defined as follows:

```html
<mat-table 
            class="lmat-elevation-z8" 
            [dataSource]="dataSource" 
            matSort
            matSortActive="deliveryDate"
            matSortDisableClear>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
              <ng-container matColumnDef="receiptNumber">
              <mat-header-cell 
                *matHeaderCellDef 
                mat-sort-header 
                [hidden]="!dropdownList[0].isActiveColumn">
                  RMT Number
              </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell 
                *matCellDef="let rt" 
                [hidden]="!dropdownList[0].isActiveColumn">
                  {{ rt.receiptNumber }}
              </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>


            <ng-container matColumnDef="receiptDate">
              <mat-header-cell 
                *matHeaderCellDef 
                mat-sort-header 
                [hidden]="!dropdownList[1].isActiveColumn">
                  PO Number
              </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell 
                *matCellDef="let rt" 
                [hidden]="!dropdownList[1].isActiveColumn">
                  {{ rt.receiptDate }}
              </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
and so on...
```

And the component looks as follows:

```js
export class ReceiptComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>();
  displayedColumns = [
    "receiptNumber", 
    "receiptDate", 
    "description", 
    "customerName", 
    "salesPersonName",
    "actions"
  ];

  receiptList: Receipts[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
      //Table sorting
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      const sortState: Sort = {
      active: "receiptDate", 
      direction: 'desc'
    };
    this.sort.active = sortState.active;
    this.sort.direction = sortState.direction;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.receiptList);
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
and so on...
```

The error I get is as follows:

```js
Attempting to configure '__source' with descriptor '{"value":"MatSortHeader","configurable":true}' on object 'class MatSort extends _MatSortMixinBase {
    constructor() {
        super(...arguments);
        /**
         * Collection of all registered sortables that this directive manages.
         */
        this.sortables = new Map();
        /**
         * Used to notify any child components listening to state changes.
         */
        this._stateChanges = new rxjs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__["Subject"]();
        /**
         * The direction to set when an MatSortable is initially sorted.
         * May be overriden by the MatSortable's sort start.
         */
        this.start = 'asc';
        this._direction = '';
        /**
         * Event emitted when the user changes either the active sort or sort direction.
         */
        this.sortChange = new _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["EventEmitter"]();
    }
    /**
     * The sort direction of the currently active MatSortable.
     * @return {?}
     */
    get direction() { return this._direction; }
    /**
     * @param {?} direction
     * @return {?}
     */
    set direction(direction) {
        if (Object(_angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["isDevMode"])() && direction && direction !== 'asc' && direction !== 'desc') {
            throw getSortInvalidDirectionError(direction);
        }
        this._direction = direction;
    }
    /**
     * Whether to disable the user from clearing the sort by finishing the sort direction cycle.
     * May be overriden by the MatSortable's disable clear input.
     * @return {?}
     */
    get disableClear() { return this._disableClear; }
    /**
     * @param {?} v
     * @return {?}
     */
    set disableClear(v) { this._disableClear = Object(_angular_cdk_coercion__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["coerceBooleanProperty"])(v); }
    /**
     * Register function to be used by the contained MatSortables. Adds the MatSortable to the
     * collection of MatSortables.
     * @param {?} sortable
     * @return {?}
     */
    register(sortable) {
        if (!sortable.id) {
            throw getSortHeaderMissingIdError();
        }
        if (this.sortables.has(sortable.id)) {
            throw getSortDuplicateSortableIdError(sortable.id);
        }
        this.sortables.set(sortable.id, sortable);
    }
    /**
     * Unregister function to be used by the contained MatSortables. Removes the MatSortable from the
     * collection of contained MatSortables.
     * @param {?} sortable
     * @return {?}
     */
    deregister(sortable) {
        this.sortables.delete(sortable.id);
    }
    /**
     * Sets the active sort id and determines the new sort direction.
     * @param {?} sortable
     * @return {?}
     */
    sort(sortable) {
        if (this.active != sortable.id) {
            this.active = sortable.id;
            this.direction = sortable.start ? sortable.start : this.start;
        }
        else {
            this.direction = this.getNextSortDirection(sortable);
        }
        this.sortChange.emit({ active: this.active, direction: this.direction });
    }
    /**
     * Returns the next sort direction of the active sortable, checking for potential overrides.
     * @param {?} sortable
     * @return {?}
     */
    getNextSortDirection(sortable) {
        if (!sortable) {
            return '';
        }
        // Get the sort direction cycle with the potential sortable overrides.
        /** @type {?} */
        const disableClear = sortable.disableClear != null ? sortable.disableClear : this.disableClear;
        /** @type {?} */
        let sortDirectionCycle = getSortDirectionCycle(sortable.start || this.start, disableClear);
        // Get and return the next direction in the cycle
        /** @type {?} */
        let nextDirectionIndex = sortDirectionCycle.indexOf(this.direction) + 1;
        if (nextDirectionIndex >= sortDirectionCycle.length) {
            nextDirectionIndex = 0;
        }
        return sortDirectionCycle[nextDirectionIndex];
    }
    /**
     * @return {?}
     */
    ngOnInit() {
        this._markInitialized();
    }
    /**
     * @return {?}
     */
    ngOnChanges() {
        this._stateChanges.next();
    }
    /**
     * @return {?}
     */
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this._stateChanges.complete();
    }
}' and got error, giving up: TypeError: Cannot define property __source, object is not extensible
```

I would really appreciate any pointers.
Thank you!

Comment: After a bit more digging I realised that I get the error each time I use mat-sort-header in mat-header-cell in the template. The error goes away if I remove mat-sort-header. Unfortunately I need sorting, so can't get rid of it.